# Proving $\sum\limits_{i=1}^k | \langle x,v_i \rangle \langle y,v_i\rangle| \leq \|x\|\cdot \|y\|$

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Let $V$ be a real inner product space, and let $v_1,v_2, \dots ,v_k$ be an orthonormal set of vectors. How do you prove that

$$\sum_{i=1}^k | \langle x,v_i \rangle \langle y,v_i\rangle| \leq \|x\|\cdot\|y\|?$$

When does the equality hold?

I've been trying to do this with the Bessel and Cauchy-Schwarz inequalities, but I can't make it work yet. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: **Hint**: $\langle x, v_i\rangle$ are *coordinates*.

Comment: Use cardinal's *excellent* hint, and look again at [Cauchy-Schwarz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality).

Comment: @robjohn: I'm sorry, but I am still very confused!

Comment: @cardinal: How do you calculate the coefficient of $v_i$ in the unique linear combination of $v_1,\dotsc,v_k$ which equals $v$?

Comment: I have used cardinal's hint in my answer (although I don't mention it explicitly). I hope that that clears things up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We don't necessarily know that $\{v_i:1\le i\le k\}$ is a basis of $V$ since we don't know the dimension of $V$, but we are given that $\{v_i\}$ are orthonormal; that is $\left<v_i,v_j\right>=0$ when $i\not=j$ and $\left<v_i,v_i\right>=1$.

Consider the vector
$$
x^\perp=x-\sum_{i=1}^k\left<x,v_i\right>v_i\tag{1}
$$
$x^\perp$ is perpendicular to $\{v_i\}$:
$$
\begin{align}
\left<x^\perp,v_j\right>
&=\left<x-\sum_{i=1}^k\left<x,v_i\right>v_i,v_j\right>\\
&=\left<x,v_j\right>-\left<x,v_j\right>\left<v_j,v_j\right>\\
&=0\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, $x^\perp$ is perpendicular to $x-x^\perp=\sum\limits_{i=1}^k\left<x,v_i\right>v_i$.

Next consider
$$
\begin{align}
\left<x-x^\perp,y-y^\perp\right>
&=\left<\sum_{i=1}^k\left<x,v_i\right>v_i,\sum_{j=1}^k\left<y,v_j\right>v_j\right>\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^k\left<x,v_i\right>\left<y,v_i\right>\left<v_i,v_i\right>\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^k\left<x,v_i\right>\left<y,v_i\right>\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$
Note that since $x^\perp$ is perpendicular to $x-x^\perp$,
$$
\|x-x^\perp\|^2+\|x^\perp\|^2=\|x\|^2\tag{4}
$$
which implies that $\|x-x^\perp\|\le\|x\|$.

Now $(3)$, Cauchy-Schwarz, and $(4)$ yield
$$
\begin{align}
\left|\sum_{i=1}^k\left<x,v_i\right>\left<y,v_i\right>\right|
&=\left|\left<x-x^\perp,y-y^\perp\right>\right|\\
&\le\|x-x^\perp\|\|y-y^\perp\|\\
&\le\|x\|\|y\|\tag{5}
\end{align}
$$
To finish off the proof (thanks to cardinal), consider the vector
$$
x^+=\sum_{i=1}^k\left|\left<x,v_i\right>\right|v_i\tag{6}
$$
Note that $\|x^+\|^2=\sum\limits_{i=1}^k\left<x,v_i\right>^2=\|x-x^\perp\|^2$.

Plugging $x^+$ and $y^+$ into $(5)$ gives
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^k\left|\left<x,v_i\right>\left<y,v_i\right>\right|
&=\left|\sum_{i=1}^k\left<x^+,v_i\right>\left<y^+,v_i\right>\right|\\
&\le\|x^+\|\|y^+\|\\
&\le\|x\|\|y\|\tag{7}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: ...and, to conclude, note that this holds for *arbitrary* $x$ and $y$, hence, it holds for $x^+ = \sum_{i=1}^k |\langle x, v_i \rangle | v_i$ and similarly defined $y^+$. Noting that $\|x^+\| \leq \|x\|$ and $\|y^+\| \leq \|y\|$ completes the proof. (+1)

Comment: @cardinal: isn't $(5)$ exactly what was asked? In fact, $x^+=x-x^\perp$ so I think your concerns are already handled.

Comment: The modulus is on the inside of the sum and $x^+ \neq x - x^\perp$ in general.

Comment: @cardinal: Oh, I missed that. Thanks. Do you mind if I incorporate the fix?

Comment: Sure. Please do. Cheers. :)

Comment: @robjohn Nice. Sorry if my "answer" was confusing. I didn't read your question as carefully as I should have.

Comment: Thanks! This is brilliant! However i'm slightly unsure about line $(4)$, could you explain why this holds?

Comment: @LHS: Pythagoras. (Or, just check $\langle x^\perp, x-x^\perp \rangle = 0$ by the definitions.)

Comment: @cardinal: Oh so you can just say that by Pythagoras, interesting. Thank you and robjohn so much for your help, it's been invaluable!

Comment: @robjohn: Right below (6) you have $\|\cdot\|$ in two places where it should be $\|\cdot\|^2$. :)

Comment: @cardinal: fixed. Thanks again for your comments!

Comment: This is a very nice answer.